# Why am I getting error although the code is fine?

Tags: c

This is the error I get:

> #error : IntelliSense: a valuse of type char (*)[20]" cannot be
>   assigned to an entity of type "char*" (ptr = text)

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LEN 20

void main()
{
    char text[][MAX_LEN] = {"hi","bye","kuku","Shalom"};
    int lines = sizeof(text)/sizeof(text[0]);
    char* ptr ;

    for(ptr = text ; ptr < text+lines ; ptr+=MAX_LEN*sizeof(char))
    {
        if(*ptr >= 'a' && *ptr<= 'z')
            *ptr-= ('a' - 'A');
    }
    for(ptr = text ; ptr < text+lines ; ptr+=MAX_LEN*sizeof(char))
    {
        puts(ptr);
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Compile your code with all warnings enabled,

Comment: I remember seeing this question just a couple of hours ago, with the exact same code and error. Can't seem to find it now though, must have been deleted.

Comment: As for your problem, think about the *types* of `text` (`char[4][20]`) compared to `ptr` (`char*`).

Comment: "why am i getting errors although the code is fine" You get them because the code is not fine.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to assign incompatible types.  A `char [][]` can't be assigned to a `char *`.

Try this:

```
for(ptr = text[0] ; ptr < text[lines] ; ptr+=MAX_LEN*sizeof(char))
```

Answer (score 2):

This assignment in your `for` loops are incorrect -

```
ptr = text
```

`ptr` is a `char *` and `text` is a 2-d array of `char` .

You can do this -

```
ptr = text[i]      // where i is index ,and will represent the string at that index
 /* or something similar  to get values at different indexes */
```

and for comparing you can do this `ptr < text[lines]` or `ptr< *(text+lines)`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `text` is an array of arrays, but you are trying to use its name as a pointer in comparisons and assignments. If you insist on doing the pointer math yourself, you can certainly do it like this:

```
for(ptr = &text[0][0] ; ptr < &text[0][0]+(lines*MAX_LEN) ; ptr+=MAX_LEN) {
    ...
}
```

Note that multiplication by `sizeof(char)` is gone, because it's always `1` in all standard-compliant implementations ([demo](http://ideone.com/pcFqF5)).

A better approach is to use a pointer to array, and let C do pointer math for you, like this:

```
char (*ptr)[MAX_LEN];
for(ptr = text ; ptr < text+lines ; ptr++) {
    char *firstLetter = *ptr;
    if(*firstLetter >= 'a' && *firstLetter <= 'z')
        *firstLetter -= ('a' - 'A');
}
for(ptr = text ; ptr < text+lines ; ptr++) {
    puts(*ptr);
}
```

Now that the `ptr` is of type "pointer to array of `MAX_LEN` characters", `++` takes care of advancing it the proper distance without any use of `MAX_LEN` ([demo](http://ideone.com/SBgYuz)).